# How to display an header image using PHP mail function?

Tags: php, html, function, email, header

How do I display an image instead of the "?" mark default image while sending an email using the PHP email function ???

[image]

Comment: You'd have to set a profile picture in your Google account settings i think. It's not a standard feature of email which php would understand

Comment: but how do other companies set their own image over there ???

Comment: Maybe with something like this: https://utechpia.com/how-to-add-an-email-profile-picture-to-any-domain-email-address/

Comment: it's outdated...

Comment: Well it says it was updated in Feburary, but yes maybe it's out of date. I don't honestly know the answer, was just trying to help if I could with ideas. Maybe someone else will have some other knowledge.

Comment: still, thank you...